# Android location manager error 'Exiting with error onLocationChanged line 152 "1"'

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I have a location manager in my Android app that sometimes works. Sometimes I'll run the app and it will get location updates (with some errors). Sometimes I'll run it and it will just throw this error every couple seconds without receiving any location updates:

```
E/IzatSvc_PassiveLocListener: Exiting with error onLocationChanged line 152 "1"
```

Here is my class for managing location events:

```
package com.company.AppName;

import android.app.job.JobParameters;
import android.app.job.JobService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class LocationListenerService extends JobService {
  private static final String TAG = "LocationListenerService";
  private LocationManager locationManager = null;
  private LocationListener locationListener = null;
  private String locationProvider = null;

  public LocationListenerService() {}

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartJob");
    startLocationManager(params);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStopJob");
    return false;
  }

  public void startLocationManager(JobParameters params) {
    if(locationManager != null) return;

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
  //    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    locationListener = new LocationListener();

    if (locationProvider != null) {
      Log.v(TAG, "Location provider: " + locationProvider);
    } else {
      Log.e(TAG, "Location provider is null. Location events will not work.");
      return;
    }

    if (locationListener == null) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Location listener is null. Location events will not work.");
      return;
    }

    // Finish job after first time updating location with the server
    NativeApp.shared().getLocationData((NativeApp app, String response) -> {
      Log.i(TAG, "Received location data response. Finishing job.");
      jobFinished(params, true);
    });

    try {
      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 0, 0, locationListener);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
      Log.e(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
      Log.e(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
  }

  private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      if(location == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onLocationChanged skipped: null location");
        return;
      }
      Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location.toString());
      NativeApp.shared().updateLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
      Log.i(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
      Log.i(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
      Log.i(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
  }
}
```

Why is this happening? Why do location updates work sometimes but not other times?

**EDIT:** After giving up for a few hours and rerunning, the app is still throwing the error repeatedly, but after about 10 seconds logs this and starts receiving location updates:

```
E/XTCC-6.1.2.10: [FDAL_OSListener] handleLocationUpdate:  failed: 2
D/LocationManagerService: incoming location: gps
I/LgeGnssLocationProvider: Intent - android.location.GPS_FIX_CHANGE
D/LgeGnssLocationProvider: GPS_FIX_CHANGE_ACTION! , mGpsNavigating =true
D/LocationManagerService: incoming location: gps
```

**Device/version info:**

The device is an LG G6 (LG-H872) running Android 8.0.0

And here is the contents of my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.company.AppName" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="org.apache.cordova.camera.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/camera_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.company.AppName.LocationListenerService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.company.AppName.AppFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: on which your trying  this and your device api version

Answer (score 6):

```
long milliseconds = 5000; // 5 seconds
float minimusDistance = 5.5; // 5.5m distance from current location
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, milliseconds, minimusDistance, locationListener);
```

Try this snippet. Hope it will solve your problem.

This is happening only, for this reason, you're not providing a minimum interval and minimum distance to get location updates. That's why you're getting this error.

Here is the link check it out - 
[requestLocationUpdates](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener))

Comment: Still seeing the same errors after making this change

Comment: Have you added 'ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION' permission in your manifest?  
Another thing in which android version are you testing and which device are you using for debugging?

Comment: Both `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` are in my manifest. I'll add the version/device info to the question.

Comment: locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 5000, 5.5, locationListener);  Have you tried with this line? 
If other versions of android are working fine. Then you've to move your code jobservice to Workmanager.

Comment: Yes I've tried passing non-zero values for minimum distance and interval. I've got the location updates working on simulators. The code in my post sometimes works. Sometimes it will spit those errors for 30+ minutes and then randomly start receiving location updates. Why would switching from a jobservice to workmanager fix things?

Answer (score 2):

This location update gets varies as per the android version. Recently Android introduce [background location limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits) in **oreo** which says:

> While your app is in the foreground, you should receive location
>   updates as frequently as you requested. When your app goes in the
>   background, your app will receive location updates only a few times
>   each hour (the location update interval may be adjusted in the future
>   based on system impact and feedback from developers).

Android recommend to use fused location APIs for below reason, you must consider it for your scenario which says:

> If your app needs access to location history that contains
>   time-frequent updates, use the batched version of the Fused Location
>   Provider API elements, such as the FusedLocationProviderApi interface.
>   When your app is running in the background, this API receives the
>   user's location more frequently than the non-batched API. Keep in
>   mind, however, that your app still receives updates in batches only a
>   few times each hour.

Please refer below links for and better approach:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService/app

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o/index.html#0

**Note: The "O" background location limits only kick in when your app is no longer in the foreground.**

Please let me know if above two links not working for you.

Comment: @SimpleJ: Please tell your device and api version

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because my device (*General Mobile GM8d*) 8.1 OS updated to Android 9 (Pie). After, I tried to take location in below way with **LocationManager**:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
      LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
      0, 
      0,
      new LocationListener() {
          @Override
          public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
              double latitude = location.getLatitude();
              double longitude = location.getLongitude();
          }
      });
```

However, after Android 9 update, I had the same error. For solution, follow these steps:

1. Restarted device.
2. After, open map application (Maps). In this way, GPS will be active by native system.
3. After that, clear cache and storage of your app and uninstall it from device.
4. On top bar of Android Studio, File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...
5. Finally, run your application on your device
6. Location will taken in 13-24 seconds, depends on your area.

Done!